# Excel VBA - Add Data Labels from Table body range

Tags: excel, vba, range, bubble-chart

I have an Excel worksheet with a table that contains columns for project name, x, y, size in order to create a bubble graph.

I would like it to change the Data labels to be equal to the respective project name but how do I do that? I've searched on the web for solutions but neither of them with succes.

Here's my data:

- Chart name: Chart 1
- Table name: Table (This one have headers and I'm
  only searching for the range within the table (data body range).

Here's my code which gives me the error 91:

```
Sub InsertLabelnameBubble()
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select

    For i = 1 To Range("Table").Rows.Count
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Select
        Selection.Formula = Range("Table").Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of my project.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Where you can see that it uses the Y column (Expected project potential) as the data label text. What I would like it to do is that it should take it from the first column in my table (Project #).

Comment: Maybe include some screen shots. Doesn't seem clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Also, which line are you receiving the error? Error 91 means you are trying to use an object set to Nothing

Comment: See [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) for how to properly access a *table* in Excel VBA. You must probably use something like `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").DataBodyRange(i, 1)`

Comment: Am I allowed to upload my project file somewhere and post the link here? I'm not sure a screenshot is enough, and I'm really searching for a solution, which should be included in my Master's thesis.

Comment: You could manually link your labels to cells.  Use a formula to pull the correct project name into a specific cell and then click your label twice before selecting the formula bar and then your cell.  John Peltier explains it on his [site](https://peltiertech.com/apply-custom-data-labels-to-charted-points/) - third heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find the solution myself. Here's my final code inserting labels from the Table into the Bubble Chart:

```
Sub DataLables()

  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
  ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select

  For i = 1 To Range("Table1[Project '#]").Count

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Select

    Selection.Formula = Range("Table1[Project '#]").Cells(i, 1)

  Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code that I use for data labels from a range. Have found this on stackoverflow a while back:

```
Sub DataLables 
    Dim ws as worksheet, DataLR As Series, pts As Points, pt As Point, rngLabels As Range, IDi As Integer, ChtObj As ChartObject
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet 

    With ws
    Set ChtObj = .ChartObjects("ChatName")
    Set rngLabels = .Range("A5:A39")
            Set DataLR = ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(2)
            DataLR.HasDataLabels = True  
         For Each pt In pts
         IDi = IDi + 1
             pt.DataLabel.Text = rngLabels.Cells(IDi).Text
             pt.DataLabel.Font.Bold = True
         Next pt    
    End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if this helps. It will update the data labels with the values in the range.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm doing it wrong or not, but I keep receiving the error: "Object variable or With block variable not set".. I have you copied your code into the worksheet macro, changed the chart name and the range to match, and placed a button to trigger the macro. What does this mean?

Comment: This should work. Please let m know if you still have issues. Thank you.

Comment: So now my vba looks like this, where I'm receiving an error ( ) in the marked line.

  Set ChtObj = .ChartObjects("Chart 1")
  Set rngLabels = .Range("Table1[Project '#]")
          Set DataLR = ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
          DataLR.HasDataLabels = True
       For Each pt In pts  ' <--- Run-time error 424: Object required
       IDi = IDi + 1
           pt.DataLabel.Text = rngLabels.Cells(IDi).Text
           pt.DataLabel.Font.Bold = True
       Next pt
  End With
End Sub

Also my range should not include the header (Set rngLabels) so how to achieve this as well?

Comment: .Range("A5:A39")  - you need to update the range and specify the fist one you would like to take

Comment: I've tried that but I'm still receiving an error in the "For Each pt in pts": 424: Object required.

Comment: It looks like the code is missing the value for pt and pts. How do I implement this in the code? It is only mentioned in the dim as Points?

Comment: You need to define the range where it will find the values for the points.